# How to make Visual Studio automatically detect a .cpp file in a subfolder?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

As it's described in the title, I would like to make Visual Studio detect a .cpp file which is in a subfolder. (It's a C++ project.)

My program automatically creates new .cpp files and .h files, but when it creates a new .cpp, it doesn't detect the .cpp file in the subfolder of the project. Even if I restart the project/program.

What could I do to make it automatic?

Does an instruction exist to tell Visual Studio/or the program to compile this .cpp file ?

Does every .cpp file have to be in the same folder? I could do it that way, but it would be more organized if the different files are in different folders.

Comment: If those files keep the same names then you can add them to project manually. If the file names are changing then you can generate project file as well.

Comment: Yes but the point of this is to not touch the program after, to make it detect on it's own the .cpp files

Comment: Just wondering, why do you have a program which creates source files?

Comment: I'm trying to do some "Data base" in C++ for a final project, you are a user who connect and you can create a class with different attributes (which is the creation of a class with attributes), then you can add data on the base of this class and the attributes which will be saved in a text file, it might not be the best way to do it but I have to use inheritance and polymorphism so..

Comment: And I've always been wondering about create a program that can wrote his own code ahahah

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't find any solutions, but I've ask severals persons, and they told me that I might have to change by hand some files automactly created by Visual studio to tell them to include a specific .cpp file. But to identify which file I've to change and if I can open them as a txt file ect.. It was too much work, then I've decided to change my project.

Thanks for your help ! And I hope this will give you a little taste of what you have to do  if you have the same problem